# Registering AE To CSE With ACP

Tags: onem2m

I am trying to implement oneM2M standard. I looked at the application developer guide at http://www.onem2m.org/application-developer-guide/application-registration

[image]

ADN-AE-1 sending a registration request to MN-CSE but the request payload contains an ACPI and I dont understand how ADN-AE-1 knows that ACPI ?

```
POST /home_gateway?rcn=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: mn.provider.com:8080
X-M2M-Origin: C
Content-Type: application/vnd.onem2m-res+json; ty=2
X-M2M-RI: mncse-92345

{ "m2m:ae": {
    "rn": "light_ae1",
    "api": "A01.com.company.lightApp01",
    "rr": "true",
    "poa": ["http://192.168.0.10:9090"],
    "acpi": ["/mn-cse/acp-805496226"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically two choices.

First, you can just leave out the *acpi* in your request. In this case the CSE automatically assigns one (a default ACP resource) to the new AE. You will then get the *acpi* for that assign in the answer to the create request.

But this is perhaps not what you want, because you might end up with an assign ACP that would not reflect the actually permissions you need.

The second method is that you create the ACP for the AE yourself. This is done very similar to creating an AE resource, just with the ACP structure. The CSE is responsible to check, whether you specified everything correctly and within the allowed permission range. In the answer you get the resource identifier (*ri*) for the new ACP resource, which you then would assign to the *acpi* attribute when you create the AE resource.

With the second method, it is a good practice to look for the ACP resource first, because it might already exist (either created by the AE as described above during a previous run of your application, or even pre-defined by, for example, the CSE admin), so you could just retrieve it instead of creating it.

You should use the structured name instead of the *ri* to access a known resource, e.g. a pre-defined ACP. For example, you would try to access a resource on a CSE with the structured name `/cse-id/cse-name/myACP` instead of the resource identifier `/cse-id/acp-12345`. This method requires you to construct the structured name, which is a bit longer, but has the advantage that it reflects the resource structure and makes the resources accessible by the path through the resource tree, while the resource identifier is very short, but does not reflect the resource structure.

Comment: In addition to the exhaustive explanation of akr, I suggest to check some  opensource implementation of OneM2M server, for example Ocean Mobius: https://github.com/IoTKETI/Mobius

Comment: Thank you for the addition. The [Eclipse om2m](https://www.eclipse.org/om2m/)  project also has a couple of good examples.

Comment: I really confused. Do you mean I should have prior knowledge that ADN-AE1, ADN-AE2 and MN-AE will be registered to MN-CSE. Because somehow the access control policies should be created before they send registration request  to the CSE. 

Let me create ACP for them manually so how do they know that their ACP is what I created for them. How do they get the acpi before they send it for registration ? Do they have also prior knowledge ? I mean the acpi and cseid is in their device configuration ?

Thanks for the answer by the way. Really hard to find something about OneM2M

Comment: As said before: The *resource ID*s may change because the are a unique identifier, so you should work with structured names here. And yes, ACPs are somehow prior knowledge, because they state what your AE is allowed to do and what to access. But you can also state in an ACP what **other** are allowed to do with your AE.  And there is also the possibility that you can try to discover the ACPs that you need. This is called resource discovery and works for ACPs the same way as for any other resource. Don't worry about security, the CSE should only return the ACPs that your are allowed to access.

Comment: oneM2M is a rather young technology that starts to get a lot of traction now. I hope that will see more examples and tutorials in the near future.